# JavaScript - Regex - Grab only matched pattern if there are multiple matches in a single line

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to read the contents of a CSS file and looking for all links to external files. I figured it would be faster to just write a quick regular expression to do it for me, however this is proving to be frustrating.

Say I have:

```
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3');src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format('woff'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3')
```

That line goes on for somewhat more, but lets just take that for now.

As you can see, there are both `src:url(...)` and `url(...)` so I figured I could just look for `url(..)` occurrences.

Here's what I tried:
Take 1:

```
var contents.match = ... // The contents of the .min.css file.
var matches = contents.match(/url\s*(.*);/g);
```

Take 2:

```
var contents.match = ... // The contents of the .min.css file.
var matches = contents.match(/url\s*(.*);/);    //no g at the end.
```

Take 3:

```
var contents.match = ... // The contents of the .min.css file.
var matches = contents.match(/url\s*\((.*)\);/g);
```

Take 4:

```
var contents.match = ... // The contents of the .min.css file.
var matches = contents.match(/url\s*\((.*)\);/);    // no g at the end.
```

All I want is an array of all the matches, either just the string between () or the whole match, i.e. url(...); Instead I just get a massive pipe out of the entire file.

What I want:

```
console.log(matches);    /// Prints ['fonts/font_1.css', 'fonts/font_2.css', 'fonts/font_3.css']
```

of

```
console.log(matches);    /// Prints ["url(fonts/font_1.css')", "url('fonts/font_2.css')", "url('fonts/font_3.css')"]
```

Where am I missing something?

Comment: `.*` will match `;` which means that the match will extend until the last `;` it finds. Try `[^;]+` instead of `.*`.

Comment: note: sites like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) are super useful when testing regular expressions (just remember to set the flavor accordingly)

Comment: Try `/url\((.*?)\)/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `.*` is a problem because it's going to match closing parens too.

try this: `/url\s*\([^)]*\)/g`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to my like you are missing ? in your expression.  Instead of this:
    `contents.match(/url\s*\(.*\);/g);`
Try something like this:
    `contents.match(/url\s*\(.*?\);/g);`

What you are currently matching is from the first instance of url( to the last instance of ).